# Why is dotnet using NET 8 for MS packages when I'm using NET 6 as a target framework?

Tags: c#, .net

I have 1 console app and 1 library.
The console app in is `.NET 8`, whereas the library is in `.NET 6`.

The console app simply consumes the library as a project reference, and has some code I created (using reflection) to figure out which `.NET` version the DLLs are using.

On the other hand, the library app consumes a package (`System.Reflection` for the sake of the example, but doesn't do anything with it).

Once I publish the console app (with dotnet publish), I was expecting that at least the package reference inside the csproj library would be in `.NET 6`, but that's not the case.

I created a sample app for you to check: https://github.com/tbragaf/TestNet6WithNet8.

In here, I have the steps I am following and the output I am getting triggered by is this:

```
TestNet6WithNet8/AppInNet8/bin/Release/net8.0/osx-arm64/publish/System.Reflection.dll; .NETCoreApp,Version=v8.0;
```

Can you explain to me why this DLL is pointing to `.NET 8`, instead of `.NET 6`, given that in the library project I state otherwise? Or am I doing anything wrong? (likely). In fact, only the library DLL points to `.NET 6`.

Maybe the DLL I am seeing is the one used by the application, but then where would the one from the library be?

Thank you for the help,

I was expecting that the `System.Reflection.dll` would be targeting `.NET 6`, given that the class library uses it and targets `.NET 6`.

---

**Update:** To ease readings, below you may find the csprojs.

AppInNET8.csproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
        <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
        <RuntimeIdentifiers>win-x64;win-arm64;osx-x64;osx-arm64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <ProjectReference Include="..\LibraryInNet6\LibraryInNet6.csproj" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

LibInNET6.csproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <PackageReference Include="System.Reflection" Version="4.3.0" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: Can you show the TargetFramework / TargetFrameworks property in the .csproj?

Comment: @KlausGütter yes.

The library is in .NET 6 (https://github.com/tbragaf/TestNet6WithNet8/blob/main/LibraryInNet6/LibraryInNet6.csproj#L4)

The app is in .NET 8 (https://github.com/tbragaf/TestNet6WithNet8/blob/main/AppInNet8/AppInNet8.csproj#L5)

Comment: "It seems that even without referencing another project (simply by having a console app targeting .NET 6 is enough to simulate this" - in which case, it would be really good if you could give that simple example *directly* in the question instead of via a GitHub repo.

Comment: `The app is in .NET 8` in that case why do you expect anything to target .NET 6? The target runtime is determined by the applciation, not the library. It's no different in Java or even Node and Python.  Is there an actual compilation or runtime error?

Comment: @JonSkeet i removed that part from the question as it could be confusing to readers since I misexplained myself. What I meant is that I created another console app under that solution using .NET 6 and the published DLLs were targeting .NET 8 as well. I thought it was more helpful to give the github repository to be honest. Let me review the question

Comment: "I thought it was more helpful to give the github repository to be honest" - no, generally on Stack Overflow it's much better if you can provide all the information inline. You can link to the GitHub repo *as well*, but if the question would become meaningless if GitHub went down, that's a problem. Really, readers shouldn't have to navigate somewhere else in order to understand the question.

Comment: @JonSkeet perfectly understand that. I will review the question :)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos i think that pretty much answer my question. I was expecting that the library would somehow determine its consumed nuget target version - but it seems it's up to the console to determine that, right?

Comment: By the way, I wasn't expecting help to arrive so quickly!
Amazing platform with amazing community. Thank you all!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output path `TestNet6WithNet8/AppInNet8/bin/Release/net8.0/osx-arm64/publish/` purely depends on the target runtime of the application. And since your application targets .NET8, that's where everything will end up. The publish step copies all dependencies (in this case your library and the dll from the nuget) into that folder, completely independent on how those where compiled.

That folder contains everything you need to run the application also on another computer (given it has the framework installed, if the publish is not "framework-independent"). It would be ugly if you needed to search stuff together in different folders. If you had any folder called `TestNet6WithNet8/AppInNet8/bin/Release/net6.0/osx-arm64/publish/` that would contain all the binaries to run under .NET 6.0.

Whatever the target runtime of your library was, it will anyway execute against the .NET 8.0 runtime if the application targets 8.0. The runtime is (with very few exceptions) backwards compatible, so that any library compiled for .NET 6.0 will run just fine against the .NET 8.0 runtime. Of course, that works forward only, so a .NET 8.0 application can reference a .NET 6.0 dll, but not the other way round.